# Which way of transfering JSON data is more optimized?

Tags: java, php, android, json, apache

I am sending a big array of data. What is more optimized: to concat data with a symbol or to send it as a JSONArray?

Data is being sent from Android client to Apache PHP.

Example of concated data:

```
data1_data2_data3_data4
```

Example of JSONArray

```
{ "Data": [data1, data2, data3, data4] }
```

Comment: Depends what you mean by "optimized"

Comment: What you will save in bytes you will loose a thousand-times over writing your own custom encoding scheme and parser and fixing bugs. What happens for example when your data contains your symbol?

Comment: There is no such optimization . The only thing i see is length of String . You can not use use concat data because it will fail at some point. While `JSON` is well supported on each platform. Go with Json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It completely depends on your usecase. From you example, here are some thoughts:

**in terms of bytes sent**, the concatenation is slightly better, as a JSON adds some metadata and symbols.

**In terms of ease of use**, JSON clearly wins, as there are libraries and standards. If you just have plain data without any `_`, concatenated data are ok. But what happens if one of you data has a `_` ? You will need to escape those and to keep track of your custom format all over your codes... (And that's just the tip of the iceberg).

In general, my advice is: **use standard data serialization schemes**, always. In case the size of the serialized data is a concern, have a look at *binary standards* (for example [protobuf](https://github.com/google/protobuf)).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter, if you're asking about optimized towards transfer size in bytes, the difference is minimal.

However, the concatenated data example that you gave will require more data processing on the recipient part as your script will have to cut the sent data and parse the symbol transferring it into a usable object.

So best to stick with the usual JSON object, as I don't think you will gain any optimization this way.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by optimization.

Realistically speaking, even if you were to parse it with a custom made function/class vs. some built in function(like `json_decode` from PHP) the time difference would be rather minimal or irrelevant.

If you can stick to the standard, then do it. Send it as proper JSON not some weirdly concatenated string.

The advantages outweigh anything else.

Answer (score 0):

to concat data will be optimized but you want to make sure your data do not have "_" or handle delimiter properly.